# JSON formatted data posting to an endpoint

Tags: python, json

I want to post the following JSON formatted string using python to an endpoint:

```
{"station-id": "FMAT2", "lon": "-97.37055556", "value": "8.70", "lat": "32.80805556", "data-type": "PCIRR", "time": "210811", "date": "170417"}
```

but when I send the data, the code itself adds quots to any single part of the above string, as follows:

```
"{""station-id"": ""FMAT2"", ""lon"": ""-97.37055556"", ""value"": ""8.62"", ""lat"": ""32.80805556"", ""data-type"": ""PCIRR"", ""time"": ""210440"", ""date"": ""170417""}"
```

Would you let me know why such a thing happens and how I can avoid it please. It must be said that, I get response 400 and 429. The following is the code:

```
import os
import requests
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from timeit import default_timer
start = default_timer()
files_in_dir = [ f for f in listdir('C:/Users/bxr5813/Desktop/Send data to 
map') if isfile(join('C:/Users/bxr5813/Desktop/Send data to map',f)) ]
matching = [s for s in files_in_dir if "json.csv" in s]
if len(matching)==0:
    print "No new report at this time"
for i in range(0,len(matching)):
    filename=matching[i]
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
            content=f.readlines()
            for j in range(0, len(content)):
                line=content[j]
                url = 'https://fathomless-journey-
39482.herokuapp.com/observations'
                headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Accept": 
"text/plain", "X-Api-Key": 'lmENUdfazMd5STedwFgodgts'}
                r = requests.post(url, data=line, headers=headers)
                print r
                print line
                j+=1
                f.close()
    #os.remove(filename)
duration = (default_timer() - start)
print "Runnung time is "+str(duration)+" Seconds that is "+str(duration/60)+" 
minutes"
```

You may put the JSON string into a .csv file and the name of the file should contain json.csv.

Comment: There's not enough information here to understand what you're talking about.  How do you read the JSON string?  How are you sending it?  Please post some runnable code that illustrates the problem you're describing.

Comment: The code is added. Thanks

Comment: Why not use a dictionary instead of a string, much easier to read, maintain, and edit... if the JSON is proper in the file you can use json.loads to create a dictionary and the requests module plays nice with dictionaries... you should read up on how to use the json module here http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios/json/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data=json.dumps(line)` in your requests.post(...) line. And on server side, use `incoming = json.loads(line)`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the isuue, I used the following code to replace "" with ". Then, the problem resolved.

```
line = line.replace ('""','"')
line=line.replace('"{','{')
line=line.replace('}"','}')
```