# Replace in Python

Tags: python, replace

I have a string like the below:

```
"{
  ""station-id"": ""FMAT2"", 
  ""lon"": ""-97.37055556"", 
  ""value"": ""8.66"", 
  ""lat"": ""32.80805556"", 
  ""data-type"": ""PCIRR"", 
  ""time"": ""210606"", 
  ""date"": ""170417""
}"
```

I need to replace all "" with ". I used the below code for that, but the thing is that " works and makes ) green. So would you help me resolve this problem.

```
line = line.replace("",")
```

TNX

Comment: Multiline strings need to be triple quoted. Also, you need to quote your quotes in replace. Use single quotes. `line = line.replace('""', '"')`

Comment: line = line.replace(`'`""`'`,`'`"`'`). Notice i surrounded the double quote strings with single quote strings

Comment: How did you get a string like that? You should be storing that as a dict or JSON or similar!

Comment: I try to send a JSON line with only one quot as follows: {"station-id": "FMAT2", "lon": "-97.37055556", "value": "8.58", "lat": "32.80805556", "data-type": "PCIRR", "time": "195350", "date": "170417"}. But when I try to post it to an API endpoint, it changes to double quot!! see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730210/json-formatted-data-posting-to-an-endpoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
line = line.replace('""', '"')
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question has already been answered but just to clarify @erip comment. you should place your quotes like this next time.

```
"""
{
  "station-id": "FMAT2", 
  "lon": "-97.37055556", 
  "value": "8.66", 
  "lat": "32.80805556", 
  "data-type": "PCIRR", 
  "time": "210606", 
  "date": "170417"
}
"""
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question ?

Comment: @MooingRawr see +erip comment

Comment: @Tushortz That only works if the OP has access to the data. It could have come from an external source where the OP can't change the content

Comment: @Wondercricket posted it before I saw OP comment that he was posting to API endpoint